# PHP - number_format different number of decimal places depending of number

Tags: php, floating-point, number-formatting

I have a problem to format numbers in this manner:

```
Original number: 8.400
Needed number: 8.40
I can use: number_format(floatval($number), 2)

Original number: 1.500
Needed number: 1.50
I can use again: number_format(floatval($number), 2)

Original number: 3.546
Needed number: 3.546
I can use again: Here i dont know what should i use. I need that 3rd decimal

Original number: 10
Needed number: 10.00
I can use again: number_format(floatval($number), 2)
```

So if number contain 3rd decimal places, and 3rd is `0`, then i need it trimmed (can use for example `floatval`), but if 3rd decimal place is different than zero then i should leave that number intact.

Comment: What if your number is 8.4501 or 8.450001 ? What is your "Needed number" ?

Comment: It can be 8.4501 or 8.450001, but also it would be okay if it gets trimmed to 8.45.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your specifications (that is, with `8.450001 => 8.45`), the following code should work for you:

```
// Returns the nth digit of a float
function get_digit($number, $n) { 
    return ($number * pow(10, $n)) % 10;
}

$number = floatval($number);
$number_third_digit = get_digit($number, 3);

if($number_third_digit == 0) {
  echo number_format($number, 2);
}
else {
  echo number_format($number, 3);
}
```

The code can be tested [here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/0c222bb07a0e53066329f51d10f8e72c8ca1832c).

**Results**

```
8.500 => 8.50
8.546 => 8.546
8.450001 => 8.45
10 => 10.00
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this out:

```
$number = 8.40;    
$newNumber = ($number == $newnumber=sprintf('%03.2f', $number)) ? $newnumber:$number;
```

If the "formatted version" built by sprintf has a float value different than the original value, keep the original value. Otherwise, use the formatted version.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
$num = 8.40;
if (strpos($num,'.')>-1) {
    list($int,$dec)=explode('.', $num);
} else {
    $dec = '';
}
if ((strlen($dec)>2 AND $dec[2]==0) OR strlen($dec)<=2) {
    echo number_format(floatval($num),2);
} else {
    echo floatval($num);
}
```

Comment: Not to be picky but... what if `$num` has no decimal part, like "8"

Comment: Amarnassan: It would trigger an error (hidden by @) and return 0, so format with 2 decimals, as requested. But come on... Instead of disabling error reporting for $dec[2], why don't you just check strlen($dec)?

Comment: Whatever, but that should be included in the code, right?

Comment: If he changes `list` for `@list`, his code would technically never generate any error. @ is an error control operator which disables errors. But it's much cleaner IMO to check for errors than to disable them.

Comment: I agree about error handling and updated the answer.